# javascript nesting array of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I keepy getting TypeError: testsession.testset[0].athletes is undefined - i have tried lots of different ways, is it not possible to have an array of arrays of objects

```js
var testsession = {};
var testsetname = {};
var testset = [];
testsession.testsetname = testsetname;
testsession.testsetname = "week9";
testsession.testset = testset;
testsession.testset.push("400M");
testsession.testset.push("800M");

var athletes = [];
var Time = "49.2";
var AthleteID = "a92";
var athlete = { "AthleteID": AthleteID, "Time": Time};
//console.log(pointer);
testsession.testset[0].athletes = athletes;
testsession.testset[0].athletes.push(athlete)
console.log(testsession.testset[0].athletes[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testset[0] is a string. Make it an object

```
var testsession = {};
var testsetname = {};
var testset = [];
testsession.testsetname = testsetname;
testsession.testsetname = "week9";
testsession.testset = testset;

//Earlier you pushed 400m directly which is a string hence causing the error later on
testsession.testset.push({distance: "400M"});
testsession.testset.push({distance: "800M"});

var athletes = [];
var Time = "49.2";
var AthleteID = "a92";
var athlete = { "AthleteID": AthleteID, "Time": Time};
//console.log(pointer);
testsession.testset[0].athletes = athletes;
testsession.testset[0].athletes.push(athlete)
console.log(testsession.testset[0].athletes[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access `testsession.testset[0]` that entry is a string. You maybe at least would like to set `testsession.testset[0] = {};` before accessing its members.

Answer (score 1):

`testsession.testset[0]` is a primitive value, a string.

The following statement will therefore not have the effect you may think it has:

```
testsession.testset[0].athletes = athletes;
```

What happens here? The primitive at the left has no `athletes` property, but JavaScript will coerce it to a `String` object, then assign that property to that temporary `String` object, which then disappears into oblivion.

So it is like that assignment never happened: `testsession.testset[0]` will remain a primitive value, and primitive values have no properties.

When you read the `athletes` property, the same will happen again: JavaScript coerces it to a `String` object, only to find that object has no `athletes` property, and so you get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working code like this.

```
<script >

var testsession = {};
testsession.testset = [];
testsession.testset.push({testsetname:"week9"});
testsession.testset[0].list = [];

testsession.testset[0].list.push({distance:"400M"});
testsession.testset[0].list[0].athletes = [];
testsession.testset[0].list[0].athletes.push({ AthleteID:  "a92", Time: "49.2"});

testsession.testset[0].list.push({distance:"900M"});
testsession.testset[0].list[1].athletes = [];
testsession.testset[0].list[1].athletes.push({ AthleteID:  "a93", Time: "99.2"});

console.log(testsession);

</script>
```

and result will be like that:

```
"{"testset":[{"testsetname":"week9","list":[{"distance":"400M","athletes":[{"AthleteID":"a92","Time":"49.2"}]},{"distance":"900M","athletes":[{"AthleteID":"a93","Time":"99.2"}]}]}]}"
```

[image]